# Store custom field with SQL transaction

Tags: entities

I have a custom module that implements a custom field.

In that custom field, I have an integer. This integer is optional. The user can insert anyone or leave it empty. If the field is empty, the next number to the largest stored must be assigned on insert.

I understand that to avoid problems of concurrence between the query and the insert, I must use a transaction. Nevertheless, I don't know where to customize the insertion query of my custom field.

I have implemented the FieldFormatter, FieldType and FieldWidget.

Could someone point me in the direction of the file where I should write the customize insert query?

Comment: Entities are saved within an SQL transaction automatically. So you could query the database and set the field value in preSave() of your FieldType. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemInterface.php/function/FieldItemInterface%3A%3ApreSave/9.1.x

Comment: Great then. I didn't know that. Being like that it's all much simpler. Thank you!